# Aviation Obstacle Limitation Surface (OLS) Creation in QGIS

Tags: qgis

The goal of this is to create aviation obstacle limitation surface and to analyse for penetrations of such surfaces.

An example of one surface is the approach. It starts 60m before a runway start with an initial width of 300m in my case. This 300M line then slope upwards at a 2.5% slope and splays at both ends outwards at 15% for the first phase. I would then import CSV with my surveyed obstacles or intended buildings to identify penetrations(poking above, below is fine) to the created shape.

There are many surfaces but I believe once I understand how to create one the rest will follow.

[image]

This image shows multiple. But for this query and how to learn it. Just looking at the red (Approach Surface).

I figured out how to apply attributes to a basic polygon to visualise it in Qgis2threejs in the shape I want. It does not appear correctly in Native 3d viewer of QGIS. My query is now which tool can I use to analyse the points and penetration of the polygon. It seems the usual items are working to analyse if they occupy the 2D same space but not using elevation to see if it the obstacle is higher than the shape in 3D.

Comment: I manually created the Surface and imported by obstacles. I've tried all of the extract by location parameters from the toolbox but somehow its not working with the elevations. Just an X, Y extent and all of my objects are underneath the polygon. So its selecting all even though they aren't taller than the polygon.  I tried search stack exchange again and no one on google seems to have been using it to vertically analyse data unless its a raster/DEM and that doesnt seem to apply here.

I cant seem to find any 3d analysis plugins either.